# Meta Query Compare with Date

Tags: meta-query, comparison

```
            $metas[] = array(
                'key' => 'event_date',
                'value' => array(date('10/10/2020'), date('10/11/2020')),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'DATE'
```

Can you tell me, whats wrong here? How can i realise an comparison between two dates?

Thanks!

The whole funktion for the comparison is:

```
    public function getReports($options = array())
{
    $reportsCPTName = ktkReports::getCustomPostName();
    $filiale = (isset($_REQUEST['setFiliale']) ? $_REQUEST['setFiliale'] : null);
    $kw = (isset($_REQUEST['setKW']) ? $_REQUEST['setKW'] : null);
    $kwyear = (isset($_REQUEST['setYEAR']) ? $_REQUEST['setYEAR'] : null);
    $datefrom = (isset($_REQUEST['datefrom']) ? $_REQUEST['datefrom'] : null);
    $dateuntil = (isset($_REQUEST['dateuntil']) ? $_REQUEST['dateuntil'] : null);
    if (isset($filiale)) {
        $metas[] = acf_reverse_meta('filiale', $filiale);
    }
    
    
    if (isset($datefrom)&&isset($dateuntil)){
        $metas[] = array(
            'key' => 'event_date',
            'value' => array($datefrom, $dateuntil),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        );
    } else if (isset($kw)) {
        if ($kw != '-1') {
            $kw = sprintf("%02d", $kw);
            $metas[] = array(
                'key' => 'KW',
                'value' => $kw,
                'compare' => '='
            );
        }
        if (isset($kwyear)) {
            $metas[] = array(
                'key' => 'KWY',
                'value' => $kwyear,
                'compare' => '='
            );
        } else {
            $metas[] = array(
                'key' => 'KWY',
                'value' => date('Y'),
                'compare' => '='
            );
        }
    }
    
    
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $reportsCPTName,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'ktksort',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 250,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    if (isset($options['single']) && $options['single']) {
        $args['p'] = $options['single'];
    }
    switch ($this->getUserGroup()) {
        case ktkRechteUserGroup::Akzente:
            if (! isset($_REQUEST['allUnread']) && ! isset($options['allUnread']) && ! isset($options['single'])) {
                $metas[] = array(
                    'key' => 'kunde_id',
                    'value' => $_SESSION['kunde'],
                    'compare' => '='
                );
            }
            if (! isset($options['allOfKunde']) && ! isset($options['single'])) {
                $metas[] = array(
                    'key' => 'freigabe',
                    'value' => '0',
                    'compare' => '='
                );
            }
            if (! isset($options['stats'])) {
                $args['posts_per_page'] = 10;
                if ($this->reportPaged > 0) {
                    $page_offset = ($this->reportPaged - 1) * $args['posts_per_page'];
                    $args['offset'] = $page_offset;
                }
            }
            break;
        case ktkRechteUserGroup::Kunde:
        case ktkRechteUserGroup::KundeVertrieb:
            if (isset($_REQUEST['allUnread']) || isset($options['allUnread'])) {
                $metas[] = array(
                    'key' => 'gesehen_kunde',
                    'value' => '0',
                    'compare' => '='
                );
            }
            $metas[] = array(
                'key' => 'kunde_id',
                'value' => $this->UserRechteObj->kunde->ID,
                'compare' => '='
            );
            $metas[] = array(
                'key' => 'freigabe',
                'value' => '1',
                'compare' => '='
            );
            if (! isset($options['stats'])) {
                $args['posts_per_page'] = 10;
                if ($this->reportPaged > 0) {
                    $page_offset = ($this->reportPaged - 1) * $args['posts_per_page'];
                    $args['offset'] = $page_offset;
                }
            }
            break;
        case ktkRechteUserGroup::Freelancer:
            $fils = array();
            foreach ($this->UserRechteObj->filialen as $fil) {
                $fils[] = $fil->ID;
            }
            $metas[] = array(
                'key' => 'kunde_id',
                'value' => $_SESSION['kunde'],
                'compare' => '='
            );
            $metas[] = array(
                'key' => 'filiale_id',
                'value' => $fils,
                'compare' => 'in'
            );

            $admin_user_id_override = null;
            if (current_user_can('manage_options')) {
                $admin_user_id_override = (isset($_REQUEST['admin_user_id_override']) ? $_REQUEST['admin_user_id_override'] : null);
            }

            if ($admin_user_id_override) {
                $metas[] = array(
                    'key' => 'erfasser',
                    'value' => $admin_user_id_override,
                    'compare' => '='
                );
            } else {
                $metas[] = array(
                    'key' => 'erfasser',
                    'value' => get_current_user_id(),
                    'compare' => '='
                );
            }
            break;
    }
    if (isset($metas)) {
        $meta = buildMetaAnd($metas);
        $args = array_merge($meta, $args);
    }

    if (isset($options["search"])) {
        add_filter('posts_where', array(
            $this,
            'title_filter'
        ), 10, 2);
        $args['search_for_text'] = $options["search"];
        ktkDebug::ktkdeb('Content QS', $args);
        $q = query_posts($args);
        remove_filter('posts_where', array(
            $this,
            'title_filter'
        ), 10);
    } else {
        ktkDebug::ktkdeb('Content Q', $args);
        $q = query_posts($args);
    }

    ktkDebug::ktkdeb('getContentResult', count($q));
    return $q;
}
```

I tried stuff like &datefrom=2017-12-14&dateuntil=20201217 and &datefrom=20171214&dateuntil=2020-12-17 and there are a lot of things to show, but he did not find a single one.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is the date format. I tried it with the format 2020/10/10 (YYYY/MM/DD) and it worked as expected. You can also use hyphens as delimiters (YYYY-MM-DD), or omit them entirely. Since you've already formatted the date, you don't need to use the *date()* function.

```
$metas[] = array(
'key' => 'event_date',
'value' => array('2020/10/10', '2020/10/11'),
'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
'type' => 'DATE' );
```

Comment: Unfortunately it do not work for me. Maybe there is an general problem in this funktion with dates or the comparison?
The thing is, it is an existing function in a module that does not come from me and the function normally does just do something like "show stuff from an kalendarweek" or "show stuff from an entire year". So this is not not a good practise. Better is, if you can choose the Date. And that is what i am trying for several days now. I Edit my post and show the complete function. maybe you see, why the event_date comparison wont work. This will help me a lot! really!